# javascript unit testing : how do you keep track of all the tests you have written and what code coverage you have?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing up unit tests for a app but I'm having difficulty keeping track of what scenarios I've tested for in each method.

I'm currently using qunit and creating a testing directory for each object that I'm unit testing and a single file for each method I'm testing but how do you get a good overview of all your tests in an easy to digest form?

Ideally I'd like to have something

- which could take my unit tests and add the test description next to the function which it relates to in the code itself so when in the code I can see the tests I've got for the method straight away
- have some sort of easy to read overview of all my tests

Does anyone have any recommendations of tools or practices which may help out with this problem?

Comment: You might find this useful: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171589/javascript-code-coverage-with-jasmine

Answer (score 0):

The projects I've worked on have all been Server+Client projects, where we had a suite of unit tests for our server side code, and wanted to integrate our client side unit tests into that process.

In that case, I have written a "Unit Test" in my server side code that opened up each QUnit test in a browser, then scraped the DOM for success/failure entries, and called Assert(false, text_scraped_from_dom). Then all of my qUint tests were run as part of my CI build and showed up as failing tests there.

I have done this for Java with httpunit, and for .NET with watin.