# JavaScript code coverage with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, jasmine

We are planning to introduce JavaScript unit testing in our project and so far Jasmine appears to be one of the better BDD unit testing frameworks for JavaScript. Now I am wondering how can we monitor code coverage of our JavaScript code. Are there any tools/plugins that we could use? We are a Microsoft shop and use .NET/MVC 4.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is the [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) code coverage tool. And, as there is a [grunt plugin for Istanbul/Jasmine](https://github.com/maenu/grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul) it should work with Jasmine.

Comment: For node, see [Setting up Istanbul with Jasmine on NodeJS](https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-istanbul-with-jasmine/) by Bryce Fisher-Fleig

Answer (score 13):

A quick Googling turns up this [blog post](http://blog.johnryding.com/post/46757192364/javascript-code-coverage-with-phantomjs-jasmine-and) evaluating a bunch of options: [Istanbul](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/), [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/), [Blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/), and [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/).

For Rails, the [jasmine-coverage](https://github.com/firstbanco/jasmine-coverage) (based on [JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/manual.html)) gem gives you a Rake task that generates output in different formats

Comment: blog post is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks @SyedAqeelAshiq! Fortunately the content was captured by Archive.org's Wayback Machine... https://web.archive.org/web/20140711015527/http://blog.johnryding.com/post/46757192364/javascript-code-coverage-with-phantomjs-jasmine-and

Answer (score 2):

May be a little bit late, but if test coverage is important, you can also try [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) which has a built-in support for test coverage, a good reputation too, a syntax close to jasmine and a good integration (grunt, karma, ...)

Comment: +1 for Mocha. I use both Jasmine and Mocha, and they do have a similar feel. Mocha + ShouldJS makes for a very flexible testing framework.