# How to get code coverage of javascript using cucumber?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am using gem '**Simplecov**' to generate the code coverage for ruby(.rb file) using cucumber but my UI code is in **JavaScript**.

**How i get the code coverage of Javascript using Cucumber?
Is there any gem or tool available to get the code coverage of Javascript?**

Please give comments on that issue.

Comment: There are several Javascript coverage tools listed for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171589/javascript-code-coverage-with-jasmine. I don't know how easy or hard it is to set one of them up to work during a Cucumber scenario; that would be a good SO question. If you're looking for an answer to the latter question you might want to edit accordingly.