# code coverage for cucumber.js?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, cucumberjs

I am just struggeling if there is solution to do a code coverage analysis of the tested code which was executed in javascript cucumber?

Also the code coverage should be provided in the cobertura file format to embed it in our existing analysis of the backend code.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: found one similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538879/how-to-get-code-coverage-of-javascript-using-cucumber but it focuses on cucumber and not cucumber-js

Answer (score 5):

You should use [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/). JSCover will provide you different types of code coverage, which you can use. The type of usage depends on your needs. I have so far had no limitations with using JSCover on any js project. See also the [JSCoverManual](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#execModes).