# how to perform complete code coverage with selenium web

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing a web app based on `sencha touch` with `selenium web driver`. My test code is written in Java using testng framework of eclipse.I am using selenium web driver for accessing my web app. Now I want to measure my test code coverage i.e. how much of my js code is hit by the tests. After googling i came to know about istanbul and jSCover but i am not sure they can we used with my tests. Are there any alternative i can use.??

My webapp is running on apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a quick search , I could find out that these are some code coverage tools currently widely used for javascript

```
Istanbul
Karma (formerly Testacular)
Blanket.js
JSCover
```

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171589/javascript-code-coverage-with-jasmine) and a [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140711015527/http://blog.johnryding.com/post/46757192364/javascript-code-coverage-with-phantomjs-jasmine-and) on same topic, you asked.

[Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) with [wallaby.js](https://wallabyjs.com/) can also be used for code coverage

I think Istanbul can integrate with Sencha applications as is mentioned about Sencha test [here](https://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-test-is-now-generally-available/).In the link above, have a look at the section "How Sencha Test Can Help You"
and I am quoting from their site

> It should be very simple for developers and test automation engineers
>   to identify and write tests for Ext JS components.

Comment: I want to ask Istanbul works on extjs. As sencha touch 2 is based on extjs

Comment: Can i get code coverage with Istanbul on my test Suite based on selenium webdriver written in Java using Testng. or I have to make unit test using jasmine and then get code coverage

Comment: I am able to get code coverage with Istanbul here is the link of blog which helps me https://medium.com/@the1mills/front-end-javascript-test-coverage-with-istanbul-selenium-4b2be44e3e98

Comment: @Zakir saifi If you think the info, I provided, helped you in any way, you may upvote.